# Changing App Icon in App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have built an app using MIT's App Inventor 2 and published it to the Google Play store but the icon that appears on the user's home screen is still the default app inventor icon even after I have uploaded all of the required graphics on Google Play.

If any of you know how to change the icon that appears on the user's home screen within App Inventor or when submitting the app to Google Play that would be extremely helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties for Screen1 there is a place to put in "Icon". Upload your file (png) is preferred and select it as your icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on Screen 1 on the left side, the properties,menu for screen 1 will display on right side.

Scroll down and you will see the icon setting where you can choose an image.

Usually a 36x36 image is about perfect for an icon